# Fetching Django Objects using the __str__ method

Tags: django, object, oop, methods, django-forms

I have this Django model called `Clause` and I have a `__str__` method defined for it.
Now I have a form that displays a dropdown for the clauses, but when I POST that form, it converts those clauses to strings, whereas I need the `Clause` objects. Is there a way to get the clause if I have it's `.__str__()`?
The model:

```
class Clause(models.Model):
   reference_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   title            = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   
   def __str__(self):
       return self.reference_number + ": " + self.title
```

Comment: Can you post code too

Comment: It does not convert these to strings, it *renders* these as strings... If you use a `ModelForm`, it will work with the primary key as value, and thus can effectively obtain the object.

Comment: That's the thing...I am not using a model form ;-;

Answer (score 0):

In your `__str__` method you probably have used the name, title or another attribute of the `Clause`. You can use that attribute to get the particular object.

If your `Clause` definition is like so:

```
class Clause(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

In your view function:

```
# Get the requested_title from the request
Clause.objects.get(title=requested_title)
```

Comment: Actually what's happening is that instead of self.title, the __str__ method is returning self.title: + " " + self.date, so I can't access the object directly.

Comment: I'm sorry...I should have included the code as well :'(